# laravel - define constant for ip in order not to call function

Tags: laravel, ip, constants

I want to call the function $request->ip() once and put the ip in a constant in order not to call the function each time needed. so resource usage will decrease due to not calling function 10 times in a page while it would be possible to only echo the defined constant that had been fetched from that function once.

Is it possible in Laravel? if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)

Overwrite the `login()` method in your `LoginController` and add something like this:

```
if(!\Session::has('user_ip'))
            \Session::put('user_ip',$request->ip());
```

Full method:

```
 /**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        if(!\Session::has('user_ip'))
            \Session::put('user_ip',$request->ip());
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Remember to import \Illuminate\Http\Request:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Now you can use `Session::get('user_ip')` everywhere

Comment: by this way user can login with a vpn/pro*xy and afterwards he can change his ip, and because we have only checked if session has ip or not, so it returns true however the ip set there is the previous one which is fake! I want to check each time a page loads set the value to a constant and use it on that page!!

Comment: Then do it on a provider and update it always, apply your logic. If you don't provide us the full logic we can't reach the full answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe calling `$request->ip()` use more resources than calling a session or even a constant.

The IP can always be accessed in any php requests using the `$_SERVER`superglobal, and `$request->ip()` is just a wrapper for that.

Comment: $_SESSION is superglobal too

Comment: pay attention that in each page I have multiple sections which are getting the ip, if I have one call and set it to a constant will surely use less resource than calling a function multiple times!

Comment: if you are not calling the function a million times, as I said, it should not be a performance issue. If you are, refactor your code :)